# drupal_get_title returns empty

Tags: 6, hooks

I'm tracking pages in Drupal. I use a [`drupal_get_title`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_title/6) to call the titles of the pages, however for some pages `drupal_get_title` return empty like titles of views.   What is missing?

The title is called from a custom module. I am using the `hook_init` where it's called a function where track the pages and they are saved in the database.  I'm trying to save in the database the title, timestamp, path, etc. but from the views the [`drupal_get_title`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_title/6) return empty (the path and timestamp is saved).  The titles in the nodes are saved in the database.

How can I get the titles in the track that return empty?

Comment: What sort of pages does it return empty for (nodes/views/custom pages)? Also where are you calling `drupal_get_title()` from (theme layer/in a module/in PHP code directly inserted into a block or node)?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  They are templates with views embed. I need to detect all titles, including the views, templates and block and nodes.  The title is called from a custom module.  I saved the title in the database and I print the titles in a page with other data.

Comment: I think that your issue could be related with an execution order problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511810/why-does-drupal-get-title-return-empty-on-a-views-page